# How can I efficiently untar files on a remote server using Python and `ssh`, without taking hours to complete?

Tags: ssh, remote-server

Need to automate untar operation on remote server from local server by using python script.

I tried below approach.
This takes more than 2 hrs to untar 2GB of file on remote server using script.

if i just use:

### from shell cmdline of local server:

```
time ssh root@remote_server_ip "unpigz -dc --fast -p 16 {source_filename} | (cd {destination_path} && tar xf -)"
real    0m5.441s
user    0m0.064s
sys     0m0.196s
```

it gets completes in some seconds, but running from script takes hrs to complete.

### log snippet using script from local server:

```
2023-05-24 **20:38:58,370**             test_logger:426  : INFO         ===== start of test case: Proxy_settings_and_env_settings_on_remote_server =====
Setting up SSH connection with remote_server...
Established!
CMD: mv /opt/network.tar.gz /run/network.tar.gz
Check if destination path /run present.
CMD: ls /run
Destination path is already present.
CMD: unpigz -dc --fast -p 16 /run/network.tar.gz | (cd /run && tar xf -)
tar file extraction started...


^**C2023-05-24 23:59:38,804 **            test_logger:657  : ERROR        Execution stopped by the user
2023-05-24 23:59:38,810             test_logger:658  : ERROR        Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Here tried to use 16 cores of remote but of no use.

### code logic:

```
def untar_given_file(conn, source_filename, destination_path):
    """ Untar given tar.gz file to provided location
    :param conn: Local or remote connection
    :type conn: Object type e.g. network_connect.RPyCConnection or
    network_connect.LocalConnection or network_connect.SSHConnection
    :param source_filename: full name of tarfile with complete path
    :type source_filename: String e.g. '/opt/network.tar.gz'
    :param destination_path: Destination path to where need to do untar
    :type destination_path: String e.g. /opt
    :return: True on success False on failure
    :rtype: Boolean
    """
    try:
        # Create dst dir if not present
        print(f"Check if destination path {destination_path} present.")
        if bringup.does_exist(conn, destination_path):
            print(f"Destination path is already present.")
        else:
            print("destination path not present creating it...")
            if not bringup.create_folder(conn, destination_path):
                return False
            print("Folder create success.")

        if source_filename.endswith('tar.gz'):
            cmd = f"unpigz -dc --fast -p 16 {source_filename} | (cd {destination_path} && tar xf -)"
            print(f"CMD: {cmd}")
            print("tar file extraction started...")
            output = conn.execute_command(cmd, shell=True)
            print("tarfile extraction success")
            return True
        else:
            print("source tar file extension is not proper")
            return False
    except Exception as Err:
        print(f"Tarfile extraction failed with error:{Err}")
        return False
```

Here,
bringup is custom library which does remote operations using ssh implementation.